# DataTables Row Grouping and scroll

Tags: jquery, datatables

Currently am working on datatable plugin 1.9.4. with Row Grouping add-on ([see there](http://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html)). I want to add a vertical scroll for each group.

Any ideas?

Thanks.